# Can I block some network communications directed to specific URLs in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a third-party library for my application.

However, it seems that this library is doing network communication that I did not intend.

In this case, is there a way to block network communication directed to a specific url?

I need to prevent unintended communications for security issues.

The way I tried was to make a subclass of URLProtocol and check the url of the request.
If the request directed to the target url, I called the blow function.

```
client?.urlProtocol(self, didFailWithError: error)
```

But when I checked the network packet by third-party application downloaded from the appstore, my application still communicated with the target urls.

Is there any way to block network communications directed to the certain urls?

Comment: _”… this library is doing network communication that I did not intend”_, then why use it at all?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Because it is an SDK provided by the company that produces the hardware I need to use. I wrote wrong term. Not library but SDK. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

URLProtocol may not cover all bases.

You need to use ATS (App Transport Security)

Open `info.plist`, add `NSAppTransportSecurity`, add dictionary for `NSExceptionDomains`, and specify the domains you want to block and set the `NSIncludesSubdomains` and `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` keys.

Simple example would look like that

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>https://www.google.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```